# What test am I taking, anyways‽

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

On a recent math test, I had the following question showing a series of six images. The answer was one of the five options A, B, C, D, or E.

[image: Puzzle image]

**Can you tell me what the correct answer is? And can you tell me what field of math the test was on?**

Comment: +1 just for the interrobang.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should answer this test with:

> **B**. But hang on, there are no options associated with these 5 letters...? That's because it's the *letters themselves* we need to consider! So our answer is literally **the letter B**.

Why? Because this test is in:

> **[Topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology)**, and we are expected to consider the **number of holes in each object**.

If we do that, we see we have:

> Pretzel = **3** holes;
>  Straw = **1** hole (not 2, note);
>  Button = **4** holes;
>  Ring = **1** hole;
>  Symbol = **5** holes;
>  Target riddled with bullet-holes = **9** holes (several of the original bullet-holes have joined together, note).

Note that we have a pattern here:

> These numbers are the first digits of **pi**: 3.14159... This means our next answer needs to represent the next digit of pi, which is '2'. Which of our options here has 2 holes? Why, that would be **the letter B**!

Comment: I am sure, that your reasoning is correct. I just thought that there is a much easier solution... when looking at your numbers, then the number 2 is missing... and that could meen that the second letter is the answer... but of course this would have nothing to do with maths...

Comment: @Tode But then that wouldn't explain the entire puzzle. For example, (in addition to the mathematical nature of the setting) why there is a '9' in there (which would mean that 5, 7 and 8 are also 'missing'...), why two 1's but only one of each of the others...? Unless it can explain the whole presentation of the puzzle, it wouldn't really be a satisfying solution...

Comment: ^ Correction to comment above: "**6**, 7 and 8", not 5...